# kendo grid Add New Record is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using editor template for editing record. But I **add foreign key column** in bound fields, **Add new Button** is stop working, but edit work correctly. Here is my code.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcTestApp.Models.VM.ReferralViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(i => i.ReferralDate).Title("Date");
        c.ForeignKey("AssignedMD.ID", (SelectList)ViewData["UserList"]).Title("Assigned MD").Width(200); // When I comment this line, then It works fine
c.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit();
            cmd.Destroy();
        });

    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .ToolBar(tb => tb.Create())
            .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("ReferralEdit"))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
        dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(i => i.ID);
            model.Field(i => i.ID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(i => i.AssignedMD.ID).DefaultValue(1);
        })
        .Create(i => i.Action("ReferralCreate", "Referral"))
        .Read(i => i.Action("ReferralRead", "Referral"))
        .Update(i => i.Action("ReferralUpdate", "Referral").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        .Destroy(i => i.Action("ReferralDelete", "Referral"))
```

When I comment this line, then It works fine
 `c.ForeignKey("AssignedMD.ID", (SelectList)ViewData["UserList"]).Title("Assigned MD").Width(200);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an editor in grid column bound. not the foregin key column as this column is read only and will not post back the dropdownlist selection value to the create function in you controller

**************************Grid Model* **************************

```
public Class ReferralViewModel{

public DateTime UserEditorModel {get; set;}

//along with other grid mode
public UserEditorModel User {get; set;}

}
public Class UserEditorModel 
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}

}
```

******************************* Grid********************************

```
.Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(i => i.ReferralDate).Title("Date");
          c.Bound(i=>i.User).EditorTemplateName("UserListEditor")
          .ClientTemplate("#=User.UserName#");
     }

c.Command(cmd => {
            cmd.Edit();
            cmd.Destroy();
        });

    })
```

*****************Editor*************************

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("User") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property    
    .DataValueField("UserId") 
    .DataTextField("UserName")    
    .BindTo(ViewBag.UserList) 
 )
```

********************** Create Method **************************

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ReferralViewModel Model)
{
       //e.g
       var userId=Model.User.UserId;

 }
```

regards
Shahzad